# Creating and assigning CGRect to a UIView within a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, uiview, cgrect

I am looping through a [UIView], setting their frames, then adding them as subviews to a UIScrollView. In the code I am assigning a random background colour so I can differentiate the views from each other for testing purposes:

```
for i in 0...questionViews.count - 1 {
    let hue: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 256) / 256
    let saturation: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 128) / 256 + 0.5
    let brightness: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 128) / 256 + 0.5

    questionViews[i].backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1)

    questionViews[i].frame = CGRect(x: screen.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: screen.width, height: screen.height)
    questionsScrollView!.addSubview(questionViews[i])
}
```

However, if I loop through these and print them:

```
for i in 0...questionViews.count - 1 {
    print(questionViews[i].frame)
}
```

the result will be:

```
(3000.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
(3000.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
(3000.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
(3000.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
(3000.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
(3000.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
(3000.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
(3000.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
(3000.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
```

Why does every CGRect have final value of x from the for-loop?

**Edit:**

The `questionViews` array is set in the init with just empty `CGRects` to begin with:

```
questionViews = [UIView](count: numberOfQuestions, repeatedValue: UIView(frame: CGRect()))
```

Comment: Please include how you're creating `questionViews` array

Comment: @SamM: Updated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating an array with repeated values of a reference type , it only creates one item and points all indexes to that. So in your for loop you're acutely setting the frame of all indexes of that one UIView over and over again.

replace this:

```
questionViews = [UIView](count: numberOfQuestions, repeatedValue: UIView(frame: CGRect()))
```

with

```
var questionViews = [UIView]()
for _ in 0..<numberOfQuestions {
    questionViews.append(UIView(frame: CGRect()))
}
```